# ImportError: Could not import settings. Is it in path?

Tags: python, django

I'm getting an import error while I try to run a script in my Django app.

It is related to the settings file.

Error:

```
  File "bookd/get_data.py", line 10, in <module>
    from models import UserProfile
  File "/home/hiccup/DataProjects/goodread/bookda/bookd/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'bookda.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named bookda.settings
```

I know its a very basic error and there have been answers to solve it but I'm just not able to solve it irrespective of whichever way I try to add the path for the settings to work. And its rather frustrating that other django apps on my system work perfectly fine.

Hierarchy:

```
bookda/settings.py
bookda/books/script.py
```

I get the error while running the script.py.

Comment: You should probably mention where your bookda/settings.py file is located in the file hierarchy.

Comment: I have stated the hierarchy.

Comment: There should also be an `__init__.py` file in bookda (and in bookda/books).

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to write a custom script which uses your Django model[s], you'll need to ensure that Django can find your project package. Put this at the top of your script `get_data.py`...

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/hiccup/DataProjects/goodread')
```

...then it should be able to import the `bookda` module.

You might also have to tell Django where the settings file is, in which case you'll need...

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append('/home/hiccup/DataProjects/goodread')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'bookda.settings'

# Now we can import Django stuff
from models import UserProfile
...
```

Comment: This time the error changed to: ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

Comment: Ok! Where exactly should I put that code? It still continues to give the same error after I used your updated answer in my get_data.py script

Comment: @Hick That code needs to be before you try to import anything from Django.

Comment: Phew! So, that was the issue. So bloody dumb of me. I had actually written this code a long time back but had imported the models before it. Excuse me as I go and jump into a bowl of fire.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that your settings.py has a syntax error or other error that means it can't be executed. In some circumstances that leads to import errors.

Put a `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` first in the file and you can debug it. If it doesn't enter the debugger, then Python truly did not find the file.